# Render HTML inside a Material-UI Card with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following < CardHeader /> component inside a < Card />.

```
<CardHeader
title={card.title}
subheader={`${moment(card.createdAt).startOf('minute').fromNow()}` + ' by ' + <div>ABC</div>}/>
```

It renders the following way:

```
18 minutes ago by [object Object].
```

What is the right way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on a node to CardHeader's subHeader props, just don't mix string and html

```
<CardHeader
title={card.title}
subheader={<div>{moment(card.createdAt).startOf('minute').fromNow()} by ABC</div>}/>
```

**[Sample DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-yl1hc?file=/demo.js)**

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap your heading in a fragment

You can separate out part of your logic to its own level. This will make reuse easier, and testing also easier.

```
const MyHeading = ({card}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {`${moment(card.createdAt).startOf('minute').fromNow()} by`
      <div>ABC</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

In the above I'm only retrieving card, but you can pass all sorts of data to your heading component.

```
<CardHeader
  title={card.title}
  subheader={<MyHeading {...props} />
/>
```